# Lucene performance impact of returning large result sets

Tags: performance, solr, lucene

Does anyone know the performance impact of letting Lucene (or Solr) return *very* long result sets instead of just the usual "top 10". 
We would like to return all results (which can be around 100.000 documents) from a user search  and then post-process the returned document ids before returning the actual result.

Our current index contains about 10-20 million documents.

Comment: What happens if you *try it*?

Comment: haha, yes naturally i will try it, but I need to really isolate the "internal" effect of just returning more rows, without having to think about cost of de-serializing more data, network effects etc. See my comment to Xodarap as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As spraff said, the answer to any question of the form "will X be fast enough?" is: "it depends."

I would be concerned about:

1. You'll trash your caches if these documents are large, especially if you have stored fields that you're retrieving.
2. Because of #1, you'll have tons of disk IO, which is very slow.
3. Lucene's performance grows [with the number of returned documents](http://philosophyforprogrammers.blogspot.com/2010/09/lucene-performance.html). So even ignoring practical considerations like "disk is slower than RAM", it will be slower.

I don't know what you're doing, but it's possible that it could be accomplished with a custom score algorithm.

Of course, just because it will be slower to search all documents, this doesn't mean it will be too slow to be useful. Some faceting implementations do essentially get all matching documents, and these perform adequately for many people.

Comment: Our plan is actually to avoid getting extra fields and to let Lucene return only the document IDs - nothing more. That is why I'm interested in the "internal" effects of returning more rows. Will the primary cost of execution be to actually perform the initial search where number of results returned is less important, or will the cost be much more an effect of number of documents returned? The article you referenced was very informative, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "initial search", but if all you're storing is an ID then #1 and 2 of my answer aren't as relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get 100,000 rows back in 2.5 sec with 27 million documents indexed (each doc has 1k bytes with about 600B of text fields). The hardware is not ordinary it had 128 GB of RAM. Memory usage by Solr was like this: Res was 50GB Virt was 106GB.

I started seeing performance degradation after going to 80 million documents. Currently looking to investigate how to match the hardware to the problem. Hope that helps you.